# retrieve values from listbox in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have created a listbox as follows

```
echo "<select name="listbox1"  multiple>";
echo "<option value="0">-Select-</option>";
foreach ($Details as $Id => $Name) {
    echo "<option value="$Id">$Name</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Now I want to retrieve the values
I try these

```
$retrievelist['listbox1']= $this->input->post('listbox1'); 
var_dump($retrievelist);
```

Which shows only first item from the selected items. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `echo "<select name="listbox1"  multiple>";` to `echo "<select name="listbox1[]"  multiple>";`